# Django Multiple inheritance with different tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I tried to create some models. I actually looked at some examples but most of them don't work. Example:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Article(Piece):
    pass        

class Book(Piece):
    pass

class Monday(Book, Article):
    pass    
class Tuesday(Book, Article):
    pass
```

So my goal is to get the value with something like this -> `Monday.Article.name`.
I want to have different tables for every weekday, containing the article's name. This is the error I get:

```
ERRORS:
Testing.Monday: (models.E005) The field 'id' from parent model 'Testing.book' clashes with the field 'id' from parent model 'Testing.article'.
Testing.Monday: (models.E005) The field 'name' from parent model 'Testing.book' clashes with the field 'name' from parent model 'Testing.article'.
Testing.Tuesday: (models.E005) The field 'id' from parent model 'Testing.book' clashes with the field 'id' from parent model 'Testing.article'.
Testing.Tuesday: (models.E005) The field 'name' from parent model 'Testing.book' clashes with the field 'name' from parent model 'Testing.article'.
```

It looks like my Article and Book are using the same name. How does this work?

**EDIT:** Using this :

```
class Article(Piece):
   article_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Book(Piece):
   book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Will result in this error:

```
Testing.Monday: (models.E005) The field 'piece_ptr' from parent model 
'Testing.book' clashes with the field 'piece_ptr' from parent model 
'Testing.article'.
```

The only solution is this:
    `article_to_piece = models.OneToOneField(Piece, parent_link=True)`But this will not generate a linking between the days and a book/article. I can only add a name to the day.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Just use a single table with a "day" field.

Comment: Well I guess i have to do it your way! Can you explain why my approach is bad? Aside from the fact that it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is because the primary field for both the models are id, and a table cannot have 2 columns based on same name, do this and it will solve your error

```
class Article(Piece):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(Piece):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: it's not actually what i hoped for but it might work for others!

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling **init** on subclasses, like:

```
class Monday(Book, Article):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class OtherDay(Book, Article):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is because, as a Python class, the super() method will call the superclasses definition only one time, while the simple inheritance would call **ini**() for each superclass.